# Scroll table on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Consider table `#table`, with several thousand rows, that lives in the scrollable container `#table-container`:

```
<div id='table-container'>
  <table id='table'>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

The objective is to allow the user to type a row number in an input field, submit the value by pressing the `enter` key and have `#table-container` scroll to the appropriate position. The form `#gotorow` is constructed with the following markup:

```
<form id="gotorow">
    Go to Row
    <input type="number"></input>
    <input type="submit" style="display:none"></input>
</form>
```

The jquery code below "works" such that when form `#gotorow` is submitted, the form's value (row number) is captured in the variable `index` which allows the row's position to be determined.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  # submit the form when user presses the enter key
  $('#gotorow').each(function(){
      $(this).find('input').keypress(function(event){
          if(event.which == 10 || event.which == 13)
              this.form.submit();
      });
  });

    # on form submission capture row number and determine position
    $('#gotorow').submit( function(){
      var index = $(this).find('input').val();
      var row = $('#table').find('tr').eq(index);
      var pos = $(row).offset().top;
   });

});
```

The below code also "works" such that on `(document).ready` the table scrolls to the specified row number.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var index = 250;
    var row = $('#table').find('tr').eq(index);
    var pos = $(row).offset().top;
    $('#table-container').scrollTop(pos);

});
```

However, if the above two code bits are combined there is no scrolling joy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#gotorow').each(function(){
    $(this).find('input').keypress(function(event){
        if(event.which == 10 || event.which == 13)
            this.form.submit();
    });
  });

  $('#gotorow').submit( function(){
    var index = $(this).find('input').val();
    var row = $('#table').find('tr').eq(index);
    var pos = $(row).offset().top;
    $('#table-container').scrollTop(pos);
  });

});
```

Any suggestions as to why the final code bit doesn't work are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<form id="gotorow">
  Go to Row
  <input type="number" id="findrow"></input>
  <span id="findrowbutton">Find Row</span>
</form>
```

```js
// Outside your .ready wrap
document.getElementById("findrowbutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var index = document.getElementById("findrow").value;
  var row = $('#table').find('tr').eq(index);
  var pos = $(row).offset().top;
  $('#table-container').scrollTop(pos);
});

// On key up
document.getElementById("findrow").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  var index = document.getElementById("findrow").value;
  var row = $('#table').find('tr').eq(index);
  var pos = $(row).offset().top;
  $('#table-container').scrollTop(pos);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a similar working solution but would really like to have the scroll event occur without having to click on a button.

Comment: Ohh ok.. just do it on keyup than.. @bggarchow

Comment: @bggarchow added the key up function